# Is it possible to use webRTC to send a stream to a peer without him sending his local stream to you?

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to create an application which  requires a user to send his local video stream to multiple peers using webRTC. As far as I've seen I am responsible for managing several PeerConnection objects because a PeerConnection can only connect to a single peer at a time. What I want to know is if it is possible to create a connection and send my local stream to a peer without him sendig his local stream to me using webRTC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply don't call `peer.addStream` for broadcast-viewers to make it oneway streaming!

You can disable audio/video media lines in the session description by setting `OfferToReceiveAudio` and `OfferToReceiveVideo` to `false`.

3-Way handshake isn't drafted by RTCWebb IETF WG, yet.

Because browser needs to take care of a lot stuff simultaneously like multi-tracks and multi-media lines; where each m-line should point out a unique peer.

Comment: Great answer! Also, thanks for the relevant code, regarding this issue, on your github repo!

Comment: Note that the spec and browsers have since changed to lower-case 'o' and a simpler structure. E.g. `{ offerToReceiveVideo: false, offerToReceiveAudio: false }`.